# Adding helmet config to express app causing 502

Tags: node.js, express, kubernetes, nginx, helmet.js

We have a full stack of Js apps running on the cloud using Kubernetes.

We have:

- Vue3, nuxt3 front-end which uses SSR ( renders from its own server)
- Node express backend
- Keycloak authentication instance, also running on the cloud
- Keycloak and front-end have reverse proxies on the Ingresses
- All front-end apps are under one domain, as subdomains

I am trying to add `Helmet` - to make the headers from the backend more secure. The first is the content security policy.

```
export const helmetcontentSecurityConfig = helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
   directives: {
   ...helmet.contentSecurityPolicy.getDefaultDirectives(),
   'default-src': ["'my.cloud.domain.io'"],
   'connect-src': ["'my.cloud.domain.io'"]
   }
});
```

As soon as I add this the callback from the node app during the authorisation process
so `/my-api/callback` the Vue app breaks, this occurs during the `code` exchange step, where the backend exchanges a code for a token from `keycloak` - so a request to `keycloak`. At this moment the front-end returns a `502 bad gateway`.

What I have tried so far:

- check for conflicting headers in the `NGINX` - I don't think there are any that conflicts - seems to be standard config

  ```
  annotations:
   cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
   kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "128k"
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippets: |
     location /login {
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  ```
- check for errors on the keycloak side, which is no doubt causing the error

  ```
   [error] 3957#3957: *40174453 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, client: 84.243.49.162, server: my.cloud.domain.io, request: "GET /my-api/v1/auth/callback?
  ```
- I have also tried with the default settings so:

  ```
   'default-src': ["'self'"],
   'connect-src': ["'self"]
  ```
- I have check the default keycloak settings for the cloud - can't see anything that may conflict with the headers.

  ```
       - name: KC_FEATURES
         value: token-exchange

       - name: KC_HEALTH_ENABLED
         value: "true"

       - name: KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT
         value: "false"

       - name: KC_METRICS_ENABLED
         value: "true"

       - name: KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS
         value: "false"

       - name: KC_HTTP_ENABLED
         value: "true"

       - name: KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH
         value: /login

       - name: KC_PROXY
         value: "edge"
  ```

Any tips for how to go about this, for someone with minimal cloud/networking knowledge?

Another thing is, how important it would be to configure `helmet` on the nuxt3 app instead - or use both? Since this has its own server.

[Nuxt Helmet](https://github.com/Baroshem/nuxt-security)

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the [Express trust proxy](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html) setting? This is highly configurable and will have an impact on Helmet. For example:

```
app.set('trust proxy', 1); // < Trust the first proxy
```

> If true, the client’s IP address is understood as the left-most entry in the X-Forwarded-For header.

Comment: No I have never heard of this. Have you used it with helmet?

Comment: Yes, regularly. On AWS for example, an application can be accessed on `https://cool-app.com` on port 443 but routed to an Application Load Balancer that forwards the request to the target group of EC2 instances on port 8090 over http. A security group applied to the target group of EC2 instances only allows connections from the Application Load Balancer security group. In order to maintain some of the helmet features running on the Node app on the EC2 instances the proxy (the Application Load Balancer) needs to be trusted.

Comment: We do use a reverse proxy to manage the routing. This is definiately worth a shot.